# Google Sheets Script custom range sort without pasting result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have a range in Google Sheets that contains a combination of values and formulas scattered in various rows and columns. The sort needs to be custom and I wrote a custom sort function that extracts data and sorts the array. However when pasting the sorted result back I loose the formulas.

Is there a way to create a custom sort directly for the range without the set/get Values?

```
function orderMyRange() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mySheet = sh.getSheetByName("MySheet");
  var myRng = mySheet.getRange("A4:L500");
  var myData = myRng.getValues();

  myData.sort(orderCustom);
  myRng.setValues(myData);
}
```

Comment: Considering you don't show what this custom order is, how can we possibly help? The only thing we can do is to say that there are methods which will sort a sheet range by its values.

Comment: @Stefan you are getting the values and pasting them back into the cells so you are loosing your formulas. Tottally normal. but please tell use what `orderCustom`is

Comment: @tehhowch: I don't understand why the customOrder function should be relevant. The sorting works ok. I only need to preserve my formulas. When I apply the custom sort on the range, it fails as it should, sort is an array function and therefore doesn't work with range.

Comment: If your comparator is value based, you can write a custom sort object that will work on the actual sheet range. If not, then you have to implement a script-only solution. And no, I did not suggest you sort the range with your `orderCustom` function as-is - I suggested that you review the format expected by the `Range#sort` class method, as it may resolve your issue simply.

Comment: @JSmith: I know that it's normal to loose the formulas when pasting values :-) See the last sentence in the question. I don't need help building a custom sort function, I need a way to sort a range with a custom function or a way to paste the sorted values without loosing the formulas.

Comment: getFormulas() and getValues() -- map them or link them togetheras a array. Run your custom sort and remap it back to formulas. Set back the formulas(where formula else set values)

Comment: @Stefan I've edited my answer

Comment: @I'-'I: This seem lika a step in the right direction. However, how would I know where the formulas are after the sort runs? The coding to map that seems pretty complex.

Comment: @Stefan use a custom sort function where the `formula` array changes the same way as th `value`array. For exemple if you use a select sort you'll have to use a function `swapData(a,b)`for both value and formula then retrieve the formula with `row` and `column`indexes .

Comment: @Stefan  Kinda why We need to see your custom sort function. If you're sorting vertically, I'd join both formula array and value array horizontally and sort them both in the same sort(but just using the value array values). Anyway this is work.. And you need to show effort in this direction and if you're struck, ask a question again...

Comment: @I'-'I: I'll add the customOrder if you want, but it's going to help you to see that it's really irelevant :-) The important points are in the question, especially this sentence is overlooked:  "... contains a combination of values and formulas scattered in various rows and columns ..." It's not easy to map it, or join it, they are everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try it this way:

1. get formulas with `var formulas = myRng.getFormulas()`
2. find how to sort `formulas` and `myData` the same way.
   in a way that if `myData[12]` moves to `9` (10th row) then `formulas` will do the same in `var temp = formulas[9]; formulas[9] = formulas[12]`.
   sort by values but apply the same sorting to `formulas`
3. put in `myData`all the formulas like `if(formulas[row][column]) myData[row][column] = formulas[row][column]`
4. use `myRng.setValues(myData)` or return the array if it's a custom function used as a formula in google sheet.

for a select sort algorithm this will do something like this:

```js
var myData = [[1], [223], [3], [2], [345]];
var formulas = [["=ROW(A1)"], ["=ROW(A223)"], ["=ROW(A3)"], ["=ROW(A2)"], ["=ROW(A345)"]];

function Selection_Sort(arr, parr, compare_Function) {
  //arr is the value array and parr is the formula array
  function compare(a, b) {
   return a - b;
   }
  var min = 0;
  var minFormula
  var index = 0;
  var temp = 0;
  var tempFormula = "";
 //{Function} compare_Function Compare function
  compare_Function = compare_Function || compare;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    index = i;
    min = arr[i][0];
    minFormula = parr[i][0];
    for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j += 1) {
      if (compare_Function(min, arr[j]) > 0) {
        min = arr[j][0];
        minFormula = parr[j][0];
        index = j;
      }
    }

    temp = arr[i][0];
    tempFormula = parr[i][0];
    arr[i][0] = min;
    parr[i][0] = minFormula;
    arr[index][0] = temp;
    parr[index][0] = tempFormula;
  }

  //return sorted arr
  return [arr, parr];
}

console.log(Selection_Sort(myData, formulas, function(a, b) { return a - b; }));
```

Comment: I'-'I proposed something similar in the comments, it seems like the right way to go. However the formulas move when sorted and the rows to which they belong don't have special identificators. Don't know how to map that.

Comment: When I grab the range with getFormulas() I don't get any values, the range is sorted by values only. I can not sort the formula range the sameway because I don't get the same input there.

Comment: I know that why you need to sort by values but keep track of what index is moved to another. I'm sorry if you misunderstand. But for me it's easy. Sort by values and apply same sorting to the formula array then merge both

Comment: I understand the solution and like it, but how can I sort the formula array if it doesn't contain the values by which the mydata array is sorted? How can I keep indexes the same in the formula array if they aren't there. getFormulas grabs only formulas everything else remains empty, no values are grabed.

Comment: @Stefan use `map` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort or use a real custom sorting function not a custom compare function